# How do I delay a command from executing?

Tags: imacros

iMacros version: FireFox 8.8.2
Windows 7: English
Browser: FireFox 31
Yes, demo macros work
Scripting Interface: I don't know what a "scripting interface" is.
Website:
Different Browsers: I want this to work with FireFox 31

If I am using the following two commands how do I make sure the first command page loads before the second command is executed?

CLICK X=400 Y=300
How do I make sure the above command page is loaded before the next command executes?
CLICK X=300 Y=200

I searched on the internet and found the "set !replayspeed" command but I am new to this and I don't know if it will do what I am asking and I don't know where to place it in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help,
quizzit

Comment: I did some more research.

Could I just place the following command between the two click commands?
!WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES

Answer (score 1):

type:

```
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

on a new line, between two commands.  This will set a delay of 5 seconds.  You could set !WAITPAGECOMPLETE, but this command is only compatible with IE.  See link below for more details..

http://wiki.imacros.net/WAIT